# Stan Model Posterior Predictions Outside Possible Range of Data

Tags: r, stan, rstan

I am having a lot of fun right now learning the ropes of modeling in Stan. Right now I'm wrestling with my model of a mixed between- and within-subjects factorial experimental design. There are different groups of subjects, Each subject indicates how much they expect each of three different beverages (water, decaf, and coffee) to reduce their caffeine withdrawal. The outcome variable - expectancy of withdrawal reduction -  was measured via a Visual Analog Scale from 0 - 10 with 0 indicating no expectation of withdrawal reduction and 10 indicating a very high expectation of withdrawal reduction. I want to test if there are between-group differences in the amount of expected withdrawal-reduction potential of the three different beverages.

Here is the data

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:46, each = 3),
                 group = c(3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,3),
                 bevType = rep(c(3,2,1), times = 46),
                 score = c(2.9,1.0,0.0,9.5,5.0,4.5,9.0,3.0,5.0,5.0,0.0,3.0,9.5,2.0,3.0,8.5,0.0,6.0,5.2,3.0,4.0,8.4,7.0,2.0,10.0,0.0,3.0,7.3,1.0,1.8,8.5,2.0,9.0,10.0,5.0,10.0,8.3,2.0,5.0,6.0,0.0,5.0,6.0,0.0,5.0,10.0,0.0,5.0,6.8,1.0,4.8,8.0,1.0,4.0,7.0,4.0,6.0,6.5,1.0,3.1,9.0,1.0,0.0,6.0,0.0,2.0,9.5,4.0,6.0,8.0,1.0,3.8,0.4,0.0,7.0,7.0,0.0,3.0,9.0,2.0,5.0,9.5,2.0,7.0,7.9,5.0,4.9,8.0,1.0,1.0,9.3,5.0,7.9,6.5,2.0,3.0,8.0,2.0,6.0,10.0,0.0,5.0,6.0,0.0,5.0,6.8,0.1,7.0,8.0,3.0,9.1,8.2,0.0,7.9,8.2,5.0,0.0,9.2,1.0,3.1,9.1,3.0,0.6,5.7,2.0,5.1,7.0,0.0,7.4,8.0,1.0,1.5,9.1,4.0,4.3,8.5,8.0,5.0))
```

Now for the model. The model has a grand mean parameter `a`, a categorical predictor representing groups deflections from the grand mean `bGroup`, a term for deflections of the different beverage types from the grand mean `bBev`, a term for each subject's intercept `bSubj`, and a term for the group by beverage interaction `bGxB`. I also estimated separate noise parameters for each beverage type.

To allow posterior predictive checks I drew from the joint posterior using the `generated quantities` block and the `normal_rng` function.

```
### Step 1: Put data into list
dList <- list(N = 138,
              nSubj = 46,
              nGroup = 3,
              nBev = 3,
              sIndex = df$id,
              gIndex = df$group,
              bIndex = df$bevType,
              score = df$score,
              gMean = 4.718841,
              gSD = 3.17)


#### Step 1 model
write("
      data{
      int<lower=1> N;
      int<lower=1> nSubj;
      int<lower=1> nGroup;
      int<lower=1> nBev;
      int<lower=1,upper=nSubj> sIndex[N];
      int<lower=1,upper=nGroup> gIndex[N];
      int<lower=1,upper=nBev> bIndex[N];
      real score[N];
      real gMean;
      real gSD;
      }

      parameters{
      real a;
      vector[nSubj] bSubj;
      vector[nGroup] bGroup;
      vector[nBev] bBev;
      vector[nBev] bGxB[nGroup];      // vector of vectors, stan no good with matrix
      vector[nBev] sigma;  
      real<lower=0> sigma_a;
      real<lower=0> sigma_s;
      real<lower=0> sigma_g;
      real<lower=0> sigma_b;
      real<lower=0> sigma_gb;
      }

      model{
      vector[N] mu;

      //hyper-priors
      sigma_s ~ normal(0,10);     
      sigma_g ~ normal(0,10);
      sigma_b ~ normal(0,10);
      sigma_gb ~ normal(0,10);


      //priors
      sigma ~ cauchy(0,1);
      a ~ normal(gMean, gSD);
      bSubj ~ normal(0, sigma_s);
      bGroup ~ normal(0,sigma_g);
      bBev ~ normal(0,sigma_b);
      for (i in 1:nGroup) {               //hierarchical prior on interaction
      bGxB[i] ~ normal(0, sigma_gb);
      }

      // likelihood
      for (i in 1:N){
      score[i] ~ normal(a + bGroup[gIndex[i]] + bBev[bIndex[i]] + bSubj[sIndex[i]] + bGxB[gIndex[i]][bIndex[i]], sigma[bIndex[i]]);
      }
      }

      generated quantities{
      real y_draw[N];
      for (i in 1:N) {
      y_draw[i] = normal_rng(a + bGroup[gIndex[i]] + bBev[bIndex[i]] + bSubj[sIndex[i]] + bGxB[gIndex[i]][bIndex[i]], sigma[bIndex[i]]);
      }
      }
      ", file = "temp.stan")

##### Step 3: generate the chains
mod <-  stan(file = "temp.stan",
             data = dList,
             iter = 5000,  
             warmup = 3000, 
             cores = 1,
             chains = 1)
```

Next we extract the draws from the joint posterior, and generate estimates of the group mean, upper and lower 95% HPDI. First we need a function to calculate the HPDI

```
HPDIFunct <- function (vector) { 
  sortVec <- sort(vector)
  ninetyFiveVec <- ceiling(.95*length(sortVec))
  fiveVec <- length(sortVec) - length(ninetyFiveVec)
  diffVec <- sapply(1:fiveVec, function (i) sortVec[i + ninetyFiveVec] - sortVec[i])
  minVal <- sortVec[which.min(diffVec)]
  maxVal <- sortVec[which.min(diffVec) + ninetyFiveVec]
  return(list(sortVec, minVal, maxVal))
}
```

Now to extract the draws from the posterior

```
#### Step 5: Posterior predictive checks
y_draw <- data.frame(extract(mod, pars = "y_draw"))


And plot the mean, lower HPDI and upper HPDI draws of these draws against the actual data. 

df$drawMean <- apply(y_draw, 2, mean)
df$HPDI_Low <- apply(y_draw, 2, function(i) HPDIFunct(i)[[2]][1])
df$HPDI_Hi <- apply(y_draw, 2, function(i) HPDIFunct(i)[[3]][1])

### Step 6: plot posterior draws against actual data
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(bevType), colour = factor(group))) +
       geom_jitter(aes(y = score), shape = 1, position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
       geom_point(aes(y = drawMean), position = position_dodge(width=0.9), stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", shape = 3, size = 3, stroke = 2) +
       geom_point(aes(y = HPDI_Low), position = position_dodge(width=0.9), stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", shape = 1, size = 3, stroke = 1) +
       geom_point(aes(y = HPDI_Hi), position = position_dodge(width=0.9), stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", shape = 1, size = 3, stroke = 1) +
       scale_colour_manual(name = "Experimental Group", labels = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"), values = c("#616a6b", "#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +  
       scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Water", "Decaf", "Coffee")) + 
       labs(x = "Beverage Type", y = "Expectancy of Withdrawal Alleviation") +
       scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,10,2)) +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
             axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold"),
             axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold"),
             axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
             legend.title = element_text(size = 13, face = "bold"))
```

[image]

Looking at the graph, for Water expectancies the model seems to represent the centre (crosses) and spread (open circles) of the data quite well. But this breaks down for the Decaf and Coffee expectancies. For Decaf expectancies the lower HPDI is below the range of possible values (lower limit = 0) and the spread of the draws from the posterior (represented in each group by the open circles) is too large. The Coffee group's upper HPDI limit is also *above* the range of the data (upper limit = 10) and the spread is too large for the actual data.

So my question is:

**How do I constrain the draws from the joint posterior to the actual range of the data?**

Is there some sort of brute-force way to constrain the draws from the posterior in Stan? Or would a more adaptable estimation of differences in the variance across the three beverage conditions be more effective (in which case this would be more of a CV question than a SO question)?

Comment: I know Stan does have some fairly straightforward ways to put bounds on data and parameters, see: https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/stan-users-guide/truncated-data-section.html . But I don't know a lot about how that would affect the validity of the model, it might be worth asking about that on CV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on @Bob Carpenter's answer, here are two ways you could approach the problem.  (I've had cause to use both of these recently and struggled to get them up and running.  This may be useful to other beginners like me.)

### Method 1: Ordered Logistic Regression

We're going to assume that each user has a "true" expectancy for each response, which is on an arbitrary continuous scale, and model it as a latent variable.  If the user's actual responses fall into `K` categories, we also model `K - 1` cutpoints between those categories.  The probability that the user selects a given response category is equal to the area under the logistic pdf between the relevant cutpoints.

[image: illustration of ordered logistic regression]

The Stan model looks like this.  The main difference is that the model fits an additional ordered vector of `cutpoints`, and uses the `ordered_logistic` distribution.  (I also changed the priors on the `sigma`s to Cauchy, to keep them positive, and switched to [non-centered parameterization](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/stan-users-guide/reparameterization-section.html).  But those changes are independent of the question at hand.)  **Edit:** Also added inputs for new (hypothetical) observations about which we want to make predictions, and added a new generated quantity for those predictions.

```
data {
  // the real data
  int<lower=1> N;
  int<lower=1> nSubj;
  int<lower=1> nGroup;
  int<lower=1> nBev;
  int minResponse;
  int maxResponse;
  int<lower=1,upper=nSubj> sIndex[N];
  int<lower=1,upper=nGroup> gIndex[N];
  int<lower=1,upper=nBev> bIndex[N];
  int<lower=minResponse,upper=maxResponse> score[N];
  // hypothetical observations for new predictions
  int<lower=1> nNewPred;
  int<lower=0> nNewSubj;
  int<lower=0> nNewGroup;
  int<lower=0> nNewBev;
  int<lower=1,upper=nSubj+nNewSubj> sNewIndex[nNewPred];
  int<lower=1,upper=nGroup+nNewGroup> gNewIndex[nNewPred];
  int<lower=1,upper=nBev+nNewBev> bNewIndex[nNewPred];
}

parameters {
  real a;
  vector[nSubj] bSubj;
  vector[nGroup] bGroup;
  vector[nBev] bBev;
  vector[nBev] bGxB[nGroup];
  real<lower=0> sigma_s;
  real<lower=0> sigma_g;
  real<lower=0> sigma_b;
  real<lower=0> sigma_gb;
  ordered[maxResponse - minResponse] cutpoints;
}

model {
  // hyper-priors
  sigma_s ~ cauchy(0, 1);
  sigma_g ~ cauchy(0, 1);
  sigma_b ~ cauchy(0, 1);
  sigma_gb ~ cauchy(0, 1);
  // priors
  a ~ std_normal();
  bSubj ~ std_normal();
  bGroup ~ std_normal();
  bBev ~ std_normal();
  for (i in 1:nGroup) {
    bGxB[i] ~ std_normal();
  }
  // likelihood
  for(i in 1:N) {
    score[i] ~ ordered_logistic(a +
                                  (bGroup[gIndex[i]] * sigma_g) +
                                  (bBev[bIndex[i]] * sigma_b) +
                                  (bSubj[sIndex[i]] * sigma_s) +
                                  (bGxB[gIndex[i]][bIndex[i]] * sigma_gb),
                                cutpoints);
  }
}

generated quantities {
  real y_draw[N];
  real y_new_pred[nNewPred];
  vector[nGroup+nNewGroup] bNewGroup;
  vector[nBev+nNewBev] bNewBev;
  vector[nSubj+nNewSubj] bNewSubj;
  vector[nBev+nNewBev] bNewGxB[nGroup+nNewGroup];
  // generate posterior predictions for the real data
  for (i in 1:N) {
    y_draw[i] = ordered_logistic_rng(a +
                                       (bGroup[gIndex[i]] * sigma_g) +
                                       (bBev[bIndex[i]] * sigma_b) +
                                       (bSubj[sIndex[i]] * sigma_s) +
                                       (bGxB[gIndex[i]][bIndex[i]] * sigma_gb),
                                     cutpoints);
  }
  // generate predictions for the new observations
  for (i in 1:(nGroup+nNewGroup)) {
    if (i <= nGroup) { bNewGroup[i] = bGroup[i]; }
    else { bNewGroup[i] = normal_rng(0, 1); }
  }
  for (i in 1:(nBev+nNewBev)) {
    if (i <= nBev) { bNewBev[i] = bBev[i]; }
    else { bNewBev[i] = normal_rng(0, 1); }
  }
  for (i in 1:(nSubj+nNewSubj)) {
    if (i <= nSubj) { bNewSubj[i] = bSubj[i]; }
    else { bNewSubj[i] = normal_rng(0, 1); }
  }
  for (i in 1:(nBev+nNewBev)) {
    for(j in 1:(nGroup+nNewGroup)) {
      if (i <= nBev && j <= nGroup) { bNewGxB[i][j] = bGxB[i][j]; }
      else { bNewGxB[i][j] = normal_rng(0, 1); }
    }
  }
  for (i in 1:nNewPred) {
    y_new_pred[i] = ordered_logistic_rng(a +
                                           (bNewGroup[gNewIndex[i]] * sigma_g) +
                                           (bNewBev[bNewIndex[i]] * sigma_b) +
                                           (bNewSubj[sNewIndex[i]] * sigma_s) +
                                           (bNewGxB[gNewIndex[i]][bNewIndex[i]] * sigma_gb),
                                         cutpoints);
  }
}
```

It looks like responses in your dataset are recorded to the nearest tenth, so that gives us 101 possible categories between 0 and 10.  To keep everything as Stan-friendly integers, we can multiply all the responses by 10.  (I also added one to each response because I had trouble fitting the model when one of the possible categories was zero.)  **Edit:** Added new test data for a hypothetical "subject 47", one observation for each group/beverage.

```
new.pred.obs = expand.grid(group = 1:3, bevType = 2:3) %>%
  mutate(id = max(df$id) + 1)
dList <- list(N = 138,
              nSubj = 46,
              nGroup = 3,
              nBev = 3,
              minResponse = 1,
              maxResponse = 101,
              sIndex = df$id,
              gIndex = df$group,
              bIndex = df$bevType,
              score = (df$score * 10) + 1,
              nNewPred = nrow(new.pred.obs),
              nNewSubj = 1,
              nNewGroup = 0,
              nNewBev = 0,
              sNewIndex = new.pred.obs$id,
              gNewIndex = new.pred.obs$group,
              bNewIndex = new.pred.obs$bevType)
```

After we extract `y_draw`, we can convert it back to the original scale:

```
y_draw <- (data.frame(extract(mod, pars = "y_draw")) - 1) / 10
```

Everything else is the same as before.  Now the posterior predictions are correctly confined to `[0, 10]`.

[image: posterior predictions using ordered logistic regression]

To draw inferences on the original scale about differences between beverages, we can use the predictions for our hypothetical data.  For each sample, we have one predicted output for a new subject in each group/beverage combination.  We can compare the "coffee" vs. "decaf" responses within each sample and group:

```
# Get predictions for hypothetical observations
new.preds.df = data.frame(rstan::extract(mod, pars = "y_new_pred")) %>%
  rownames_to_column("sample") %>%
  gather(obs, pred, -sample) %>%
  mutate(obs = gsub("y_new_pred\\.", "", obs),
         pred = (pred - 1) / 10) %>%
  inner_join(new.pred.obs %>%
               rownames_to_column("obs") %>%
               mutate(bevType = paste("bev", bevType, sep = ""),
                      group = paste("Group", group)),
             by = c("obs")) %>%
  select(-obs) %>%
  spread(bevType, pred) %>%
  mutate(bevTypeDiff = bev3 - bev2)
```

[image]

(Alternatively, we could have done this prediction for new observations in R, or in a separate Stan model; see [here](https://medium.com/@alex.pavlakis/making-predictions-from-stan-models-in-r-3e349dfac1ed) for examples of how this could be done.)

### Method 2: Beta Regression

Once we get up to 101 response categories, calling these possibilities discrete categories seems a little strange.  It feels more natural to say, as your original model tried to do, that we're capturing a continuous outcome that happens to be bounded between 0 and 10.  Also, in ordered logistic regression, the response categories don't have to be regularly spaced with respect to the latent variable.  (This is a feature, not a bug; for example, for Likert responses, there's no guarantee that the difference between "Strongly agree" and "Agree" is the same as the difference between "Agree" and "Neither agree not disagree".)  as a result, it's difficult to say anything about the "distance" a particular factor causes a response to move on the original scale (as opposed to the scale of the latent variable).  But the cutpoints inferred by the model above are pretty regularly spaced, which again suggests that the outcome in your dataset is already reasonably scale-like:

```
# Get the sampled parameters
sampled.params.df = data.frame(as.array(mod)[,1,]) %>%
  select(-matches("y_draw")) %>%
  rownames_to_column("iteration")

# Plot selected cutpoints
sampled.params.df %>%
  select(matches("cutpoints")) %>%
  gather(cutpoint, value) %>%
  mutate(cutpoint.num = as.numeric(gsub("^cutpoints\\.([0-9]+)\\.$", "\\1", cutpoint))) %>%
  group_by(cutpoint.num) %>%
  summarize(mean.value = mean(value),
            lower.95 = quantile(value, 0.025),
            lower.50 = quantile(value, 0.25),
            upper.50 = quantile(value, 0.75),
            upper.95 = quantile(value, .975)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cutpoint.num, y = mean.value)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = lower.95, ymax = upper.95)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = lower.50, ymax = upper.50), size = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous("cutpoint", breaks = seq(0, 100, 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous("") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: cutpoints inferred by the ordered logistic regression model]

(Thick and thin lines represent 50% and 95% intervals, respectively.  I'm enjoying the little "jump" every 10 cutpoints, which suggests subjects treated, say, 5.9 vs. 6.0 as a larger difference than 5.8 vs. 5.9.  But the effect seems to be quite mild.  The scale also seems to stretch out a bit towards the high end, but again, it's not too drastic.)

For a continuous outcome in a bounded interval, we can use the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution); see [here](https://github.com/m-clark/Miscellaneous-R-Code/blob/master/ModelFitting/Bayesian/rstanBetaRegression.R) and [here](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/regression-of-proportions/2375/11) for further discussion.

For the beta distribution, we need two parameters, `mu` and `phi`, both of which must be positive.  In this example, I allowed `mu` to be unbounded and applied `inv_logit` before feeding it into the beta distribution; I constrained `phi` to be positive and gave it a Cauchy prior.  But you could do it in any number of ways.  I also coded a full set of `mu` parameters but only a single `phi`; again, you can experiment with other options.

```
data {
  int<lower=1> N;
  int<lower=1> nSubj;
  int<lower=1> nGroup;
  int<lower=1> nBev;
  int<lower=1,upper=nSubj> sIndex[N];
  int<lower=1,upper=nGroup> gIndex[N];
  int<lower=1,upper=nBev> bIndex[N];
  vector<lower=0,upper=1>[N] score;
}

parameters {
  real a;
  real a_phi;
  vector[nSubj] bSubj;
  vector[nGroup] bGroup;
  vector[nBev] bBev;
  vector[nBev] bGxB[nGroup];
  real<lower=0> sigma_s;
  real<lower=0> sigma_g;
  real<lower=0> sigma_b;
  real<lower=0> sigma_gb;
}

model {
  vector[N] mu;
  //hyper-priors
  sigma_s ~ cauchy(0, 1);
  sigma_g ~ cauchy(0, 1);
  sigma_b ~ cauchy(0, 1);
  sigma_gb ~ cauchy(0, 1);
  //priors
  a ~ std_normal();
  a_phi ~ cauchy(0, 1);
  bSubj ~ std_normal();
  bGroup ~ std_normal();
  bBev ~ std_normal();
  for (i in 1:nGroup) {
    bGxB[i] ~ std_normal();
  }
  // likelihood
  for(i in 1:N) {
    mu[i] = a +
             (bGroup[gIndex[i]] * sigma_g) +
             (bBev[bIndex[i]] * sigma_b) +
             (bSubj[sIndex[i]] * sigma_s) +
             (bGxB[gIndex[i]][bIndex[i]] * sigma_gb);
    score[i] ~ beta(inv_logit(mu[i]) .* a_phi,
                    (1 - inv_logit(mu[i])) .* a_phi);
  }
}

generated quantities {
  real y_draw[N];
  real temp_mu;
  for (i in 1:N) {
    temp_mu = a +
               (bGroup[gIndex[i]] * sigma_g) +
               (bBev[bIndex[i]] * sigma_b) +
               (bSubj[sIndex[i]] * sigma_s) +
               (bGxB[gIndex[i]][bIndex[i]] * sigma_gb);
    y_draw[i] = beta_rng(inv_logit(temp_mu) .* a_phi,
                         (1 - inv_logit(temp_mu)) .* a_phi);
  }
}
```

The beta distribution is supported on `(0, 1)`, so we divide the observed scores by 10.  (The model also fails if we give it scores of exactly 0 or 1, so I converted all such scores to 0.01 and 0.99, respectively.)

```
dList.beta <- list(N = 138,
                   nSubj = 46,
                   nGroup = 3,
                   nBev = 3,
                   sIndex = df$id,
                   gIndex = df$group,
                   bIndex = df$bevType,
                   score = ifelse(df$score == 0, 0.01,
                                  ifelse(df$score == 10, 0.99,
                                         df$score / 10)))
```

Undo the transformation when extracting `y_draw`, and then the procedure is the same as before.

```
y_draw.beta <- data.frame(extract(mod.beta, pars = "y_draw")) * 10
```

Once again, the posterior draws are correctly bounded.

[image: posterior predictions using beta distribution]

Comment: Brilliant comprehensive answer @A.S.K. Thoroughly deserved the credit for the answer. I will enjoy going through your code and applying it to my problem.

Comment: how do you interpret the coefficients of the ordered logistic regression, especially in light of the fact that you transformed the outcome by mutliplying it by 10? For example the coefficient for `bBev[2]` from your model applied the data was -1.02 and for `bBev[3]` was 1.20, a difference of 2.22. Is there any way to get this back to the original scale, for ease of interpretation? In my original model I could say 'on average the expectancy of withdrawal reduction was 5.64 points greater for Coffee than it was for Decaf'.

Comment: Ordered logistic is hard because the response categories don't have to be spaced evenly on the scale of the latent variable.  (A difference of 2 points might be "bigger" in one part of the scale than the other.)  Your results don't do that much (see edited answer), so in order to draw inferences directly about the outcome scale, you might want to go with a beta distribution after all.  Or you could generate predictions from the logistic model for matched hypothetical observations that differ only in beverage type, and summarize the average differences in the predicted outcomes.

Comment: So the group coefficients from an ordinal logistic model refer to group differences in the probability of moving from one category to another when there is a change of 1 in the predictor? When there are 101 categories that makes it hard to report anything that might be meaningful to a reader. I like the philosophy of ordinal regression (it' s more truthful about the meaning of likert scales) but it's hard to convey results in a way people can understand. I like the approach of generating predictions from the model then summarising them as they will be on the same scale as the original data.

Comment: ...but I was hoping to be able to plot a density/histogram of mcmc parameter estimates. Stats are never simple are they? The standard regression model is good because you can report results that make sense but the posterior predictive checks don't work properly. The ordinal is good because it constrains the posterior predictives to the actual scale of the data, but reporting the parameter estimates themselves is very difficult. I will try the Beta model.

Comment: what are the values on the y-axis of your lovely cutpoints graph?

Comment: They're values of the latent variable mu (like in the first graph).  But they're hard to interpret by themselves because the scale of mu is arbitrary - we could increase `a` and all the cutpoints by 17 and the model would still make the same predictions.  For a given observation, what matters is that observation's value of mu relative to the cutpoints: does it fall somewhere around cutpoint 22?  Around cutpoint 81?  From there, we can predict outcomes on the categorical scale that we're actually able to observe.

Comment: so the y-axis is the expected/predicted value of the latent variable on its original continuous scale, but not directly interpretable on its own?

Comment: Yep, that's right.  Difficult to work with, unfortunately, but unavoidable in an ordered logistic model.

Comment: you suggested that to make the results more interpretable  I could generate predictions from the logistic model for matched hypothetical observations that differ only in beverage type and summarise the differences in the predicted outcomes. How do I do that? As you know I can generate predictions from each group, and I know how to generate hypothetical predictions when there is a continuous predictor, but how do I generate a "matched" prediction in the generated quantities block. Sorry for mining your brain for this stuff!

Comment: If you don't mind re-fitting the whole model, the "fit-and-predict" method described [here](https://medium.com/@alex.pavlakis/making-predictions-from-stan-models-in-r-3e349dfac1ed) may be your best bet.  You feed an additional "test set" to Stan and add another generated quantity for predictions for the test set.  The nice thing about that method is you'll get the full posterior prediction for each observation, so you can get the difference between matched observations within each sample, and examine the full distribution of the differences (e.g., are they always > 0?).

Comment: Thank you again @A. S. K.! I don't mind re-running the whole model, but do the training and test sets have to be real data, the way they do in cross validation? I don't have enough actual data to do that. You seemed to suggest in your original reference to the technique that you could generate hypothetical data?

Comment: I wasn't thinking about the complication adding new levels (i.e., new hypothetical subjects), so it's actually somewhat less than trivial.  I'll edit the post.

Comment: Thank you @A. S. K., so helpful again, you are a true scholar.

Comment: I have no right to expect any more help than that you have already given me @A. S. K. but can I prevail on you one last time to ask what data did you use for the new inputs `nNewPred`, `nNewSubj`, `nNewGroup`, `nNewBev`, `sNewIndex`, `gNewIndex`, and `bNewIndex`?

Comment: Oops; I had intended to include that code as well - looks like I accidentally left it out.  Fixed now!

Comment: Thank you again! I feel like I should wire you money or something :)

Comment: Happy to help!  I've gotten a lot from StackOverflow over the years, so it's good to contribute in return :-) .

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to constrain a posterior variable is to use a link function to transform it.  That's the way generalized linear models (GLMs) like logistic regression and Poisson regression work.  For example, to go from positive ot unconstrained, we use a log transform.  To go from a probability in (0, 1) to unconstrained, we use a log odds transform.

If your outcomes are ordinal values on a 1-10 scale, a common approach that respects that data scale is [ordinal logistic regression](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/stan-users-guide/ordered-logistic-section.html).